# How can I call a particular glyph of the Kablammo font in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Google Fonts has a [table](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kablammo/glyphs?preview.text=Hadis%20and%20Matin&preview.text_type=custom) associated with different glyphs of the Kablammo font, but I can't find any matrix of codes according to which `\symbol{glyph code}` may be called. Can one explain how I can do this using LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glyphs are in their standard Unicode position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\kablammo}{Kablammo-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}

{\kablammo aáäbcdȱ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I (hypothetically) can't copy the symbols into my editor?

Comment: @Pinton You look up the Unicode table and input `\symbol{"<hex code>}` For instance, the last character in the example is LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOT ABOVE AND MACRON U+0231 and you can use `\symbol{"0231}`.